# If/else syntax error in python

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I keep getting a syntax error on the second `else:` in this code. I've tried counting spaces, double checking braces, etc. I can't figure out what's wrong. Am I missing something?

```
if cclass == "wizard" or cclass == "cleric":
    level = input("What is your level of {}?".format(character_class))
    if (int(level)>=1 and int(level)<=20):
        print ("Welcome {}, {} of level {}".format(name, character_class, level)
    else:
        input("That level is out of range. Press enter to exit.")
        sys.exit()
else:
    input("You do not appear to be a character class that uses a grimoire.")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parens here. There are nice editors out there that might make your life easier in future by highlighting those (I admit that it is easy to overlook, so why not taking advantage of current editors)

Comment: @SebastianRaschka I've been using gEdit, but clearly I need something more helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Also you can make level = int(input(..snip..)) and then check like this: if (1 <= level <=20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the `print()` call:

```
print ("Welcome {}, {} of level {}".format(name, character_class, level)
#     ^                                   ^                            ^^?
#     |                                    \-------- closed ----------/ |
#      \-------------------------- remains open -----------------------/
```

Python cannot see where this statement ends now and throws a syntax error when it then finds an `else` statement instead.

Comment: Cripes. I was going mad looking at that. Thanks!